# Не подгружается шрифт в IE по HTTPS а по HTTP все норм

Tags: css, internet-explorer

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto Regular';
    src: url("font/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf");
    src: url("font/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf");
    src: url("font/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("font/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf") format("woff"),
    url("font/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;

}
```

я понимаю что ie использует как то свой путь из за этого в http есть шрифт а по https нет шрифта как исправить